# Sharing data structures across async closures

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I'm stuck trying to share (read-only) data structures across async helpers. What I'm trying to accomplish is create a Hyper server where I pre-generate some data that can be used by all request handlers.

Here is the example from the Hyper getting started guide, extended with what I'm trying to do:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let address = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));

    let pages = generate_static_pages();

    let make_service = make_service_fn(|_conn| async move {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(|req: Request<Body>| async move {
            serve(pages, req)
        }))
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&address).serve(make_service);

    if let Err(error) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", error);
    }
}
```

In my case, `generate_static_pages()` returns a `HashMap<&'static str, Bytes>` with pre-generated pages. Unfortunately, this hash map cannot be generated at compile-time, because that would make things a lot easier. Now, I struggle because `pages` cannot be borrowed by the closures: "cannot move out of `pages`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure"

I tried to pass a reference, but that didn't work because Rust cannot infer the variable to live long enough for the closure to use. I then tried to use `.clone()` but that doesn't work because it would be called on the variable after it is moved, which it can't. Finally, I tried wrapping in an `Arc`, but that doesn't solve it, basically because of the same reason.

What would you advice me to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want immutable references to the pages then you should be able to use the `lazy_static` crate. `lazy_static` lets you initialize static variables at runtime - it's quite useful!

Your code would end up looking something like:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
  static ref PAGES: HashMap<&'static str, Bytes> = generate_static_pages();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let address = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));

    let make_service = make_service_fn(|_conn| async move {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(|req: Request<Body>| async move {
            serve(&PAGES, req)
        }))
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&address).serve(make_service);

    if let Err(error) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", error);
    }
}
```

Also, here's another [`lazy_static` example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=377f4c9e6079a0884af2a0d421852a07).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I solve it if I do want mutable access? Cheers!

Comment: Using an `Arc<Mutex>` on each node or the whole map or using a concurent hashmap (ex: evmap)

Comment: Just like @AsyaCorbeau said, to allow interior mutability you'll have to use a `Mutex` or a `RefCell`. You can put it in an `Arc`, or you can use `lazy_static`. Here's an example using `lazy_static`: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6334d59fc3396f2ab977c7cc23df4fed)

Comment: Be careful when using mutexes though, because you can run into an issue called "deadlock"